# How to detect scroll on iOS with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, touchmove

I normally simulate elements on a scroll event with something like this:

```
$(window).on(is_touch_device ? 'touchmove' : 'scroll', function(event) {
    //do stuff
});
```

The problem is on iOS where `touchmove` only gets triggered when my finger is actually touching the iPad and not when it's scrolling "on it's own".

I'm sure there's a simple solution on this.

jQuery is used for better explanation here so the solution *can be* without jQuery too.

Comment: Read this http://developer.telerik.com/featured/scroll-event-change-ios-8-big-deal/, it seems that you can use the scroll event on iOS8+?

Comment: ok, thanks I'll check that!

Comment: the link no longer exists, would have been nice to copy the important parts of it into a separate answer rather then just posting a link